# Subsonic 3: Strongly typed return value for stored procedures that return mixed results from different tables

Tags: subsonic

Say I have a stored procedure that returns dataSet from 2 different tables. Example:

```
SELECT Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, SUM(Sales.SaleAmount) AS SalesPerCustomer
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Sales
ON Customers.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName
```

Is there any way to get a strongly typed list as a result from this stored procedure ? Something like this:

```
StoredProcedure sp = myDevDB.GetCustomerSales();

List<MyCustomType> resultSet = sp.ExecuteTypedList<MyCustomType>();
```

How and where do I define the MyCustomType class ? How do I map its properties to the actual table columns ?

thanks,mehul

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a class (in the same place as all my other classes, but I didn't extend IActiveRecord, it's just a vanilla class).

Make sure the property names have exactly the same name and data type as the ones in the procedure, then call db.sproc(params).ExecuteTypedList().AsQueryable(); and it populated fine.